# Error in the width of the div in HTML, CSS

Tags: php, html, css, margin

The problem here is that my navbar div is not covering the full 100% width of the screen, since I changed the background color, I noticed this problem and `width: 100%;` didn't help as well. I don't know what's the problem, please help me out.... I will share only my HTML code since the CSS is not working in my code so only the inline css I have put in PHP scriptlet and it the normal HTML part is working.... So please tell what's the problem. Little white area is displayed on both the sides of my navbar... Image is attached as well...

```
<div class="header-bottom">
    <div class="header-sticky" style="width:100%; height:70px;">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center" style="background-color:#ffe2f8;">

                <!-- Header Logo Start -->
                <div class="col-xl-1 col-6" style="margin-top:-25px;">
                    <div class="header-logo">
                        <a href="index.php"><img src="assets/images/logo/logo.png" alt="Site Logo" /></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Header Logo End -->

                <!-- Header Menu Start -->
                <div class="col-xl-11 d-none d-xl-block" style="margin-top:-21px; font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;">
                    <div class="main-menu position-relative">[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kGQd.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3kGQd.jpg)
                        <ul>
                            <!-- <li class="has-children"> <li>
                                <a href="#"><span>Home</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i> </a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="index.php">Home 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index-2.php">Home 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li> -->
                            <li><a href="index.php" style="font-size:13px;margin-right:-20px;"> <span>Home</span></a></li>
                            <?php
                                $query = "select * from categories where status='0'";
                                $data = mysqli_query($link, $query);
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data))
                                {
                                    extract($row);
                                    echo "<li class='has-children position-static' style='padding-left:-150px;margin-right:-25px;'>";
                                        echo "<a href='sproducts.php?categoryid=$categoryid'  style='font-size:13px;'> <span>".ucfirst($category)."</span><i class='fa fa-angle-down'></i></a>";
                                        echo "<ul class='sub-menu'>";
                                        $query1 = "select * from subcategories s, categories c where c.categoryid = s.categoryid and s.status='0' and s.categoryid = '$categoryid'";
                                        $data1 = mysqli_query($link, $query1);
                                        while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($data1))
                                        {
                                            extract($row1);
                                            echo"<li><a href='viewsproducts.php?subcatid=$subcatid'>".strtoupper($subcategory)."</a></li>";
                                        }
                                        echo"</ul>";
                                    echo"</li>";
                                } ?>
                            <!-- <li class="has-children position-static">
                                <a href="#"><span>Shop</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                <ul class="mega-menu row-cols-4">
                                    <li class="col">
                                        <h4 class="mega-menu-title">Shop Layout</h4>
                                        <ul class="mb-n2">
                                            <li><a href="shop-grid.php">Shop Grid</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="shop-left-sidebar.php">Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="shop-right-sidebar.php">Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="shop-list-fullwidth.php">List Fullwidth</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="shop-list-left-sidebar.php">List Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="shop-list-right-sidebar.php">List Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col">
                                        <h4 class="mega-menu-title">Product Layout</h4>
                                        <ul class="mb-n2">
                                            <li><a href="single-product.php">Single Product</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-sale.php">Single Product Sale</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-group.php">Single Product Group</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-normal.php">Single Product Normal</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-affiliate.php">Single Product Affiliate</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-slider.php">Single Product Slider</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col">
                                        <h4 class="mega-menu-title">Product Layout</h4>
                                        <ul class="mb-n2">
                                            <li><a href="single-product-gallery-left.php">Gallery Left</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-gallery-right.php">Gallery Right</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-tab-style-left.php">Tab Style Left</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-tab-style-right.php">Tab Style Right</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-sticky-left.php">Sticky Left</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="single-product-sticky-right.php">Sticky Right</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                    <li class="col">
                                        <h4 class="mega-menu-title">Other Pages</h4>
                                        <ul class="mb-n2">
                                            <li><a href="my-account.php">My Account</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="login-register.php">Loging | Register</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="wishlist.php">Wishlist</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="cart.php">Cart</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="checkout.php">Checkout</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="compare.php">Compare</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-children">
                                <a href="#"><span>Pages</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="about.php">About</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="faq.php">Faq</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="404-error.php">404 Error</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="has-children">
                                <a href="#"><span>Blog</span> <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="blog.php">Blog</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog-left-sidebar.php">Blog Left Sidebar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog-right-sidebar.php">Blog Right Sidebar</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog-details.php">Blog Details</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="blog-details-sidebar.php">Blog Details Sidebar</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li> -->
                            <li><a href="contact.php" style="font-size:13px;"> <span>Contact</span></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Header Menu End -->

                <!-- Header Action Start -->
                <div class="col-xl-2 col-6">
                    
                </div>
                <!-- Header Action End -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right-click, inspect. Look for padding/margin, along with parent containers.

Comment: I checked for it but nothing was there... Any other solution?

Comment: I even used width everywhere but nothing worked, is there a margin in my inline css if anyone notices then please let me know

Comment: It's probably because the body has a default margin on it. Try setting it to 0.

Comment: The class names used suggest this is probably supposed to use Bootstrap? If so, please say which version.

Comment: I tried it to set body margin to 0, thanks a lot! @Servesh Chaturvedi Sir

Comment: I am using Bootstrap 4 @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not nulled default body margin like this:

```
body {
   margin: 0;
}
```

Btw, you should get more familiar with the dev tools (F12).